# Can't resolve tsx modules even with .tsx in webpack.config resolve extensions array

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have the following component:

```
import { useAuth } from './Auth';

export function Home() {
    const { user } = useAuth();
    const location = useLocation();
    // if (location.pathname == "/") {
    //     return <Navigate to={`/sessions/`} />
    // }
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col><h3>Welcome, {user.email}!</h3></Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I used to have .tsx after auth but VS code would yell at me for it

("An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing './Auth' instead.ts(2691)")

I added .tsx and .jsx to webpage.config.js:

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');

//@ts-check
/** @typedef {import('webpack').Configuration} WebpackConfig **/

/** @type WebpackConfig */
const extensionConfig = {
  target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'none', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js','.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
};
module.exports = [ extensionConfig ];
```

Still getting a  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Auth' in '/home/app/web/src' when webpack tries to compile.

I know I can just ignore the error but it seems like importing modules like this is the correct way to do things in TSX. Why does this method not work for me?

Comment: Have you verified if `Auth` file is in the `src` directory?

Comment: Also, I think in the rules section, you have to modify the test to `/\.tsx?$/` which will accept files ending with both `.ts` and `.tsx`.